# File explorer is empty for nougat emulator?

Tags: file-system

In Device Monitor File Explorer remains always empty.why? For other emulator is works perfectly fine.Please Suggest me solution

Comment: Did you gave it the permission to access that files? That's required since Android 6 iirc…

Comment: I've created an Android bug report about this issue here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=229628